# Please provide pptpd authentication methods other than chap secrets

Tags: authentication, vpn

I have setup VPN with `pptpd` service and authentication via CHAP secrets.
What other methods are available with `pptpd` for authenticating users.
Any scope of using public keys.

Comment: If you want to be able to use different authentication methodes, you can have a look at https://www.strongswan.org/

Comment: If you're at all concerned about security, don't use pptp.

Comment: Whats alternate do you suggest for VPN?

Answer (score 0):

EAP-TLS is seen as the superior authentication choice for PPTP. However, it requires implementation of a public-key infrastructure for both client and server certificates. As such it is not a viable authentication option for many remote access installations.

In the Microsoft implementation, the tunneled PPP traffic can be authenticated with PAP, CHAP, MS-CHAP v1/v2.

Source: [Wikipedia: Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol)

However, as this is a *nix forum, I assume that the information regarding the Microsoft implementation is pointless as you are running on Linux.

As has already been noted, PPTP is not very secure anyway... L2TP is a slightly better solution, but ultimately OpenVPN is the best option. You could use `gopenvpn` for a user-friendly GUI.

I recently had the same decisions to make, and I found this link to be very useful: https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/4147/pptp-vs-l2tp-vs-openvpn-vs-sstp-vs-ikev2/